# Invalid column - ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am trying to add column headers while extracting the table data, but my query throws the following error:

> Invalid column name 'JobTaskID'.
> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.

This is my query

```
SELECT 
    'JobTaskID', 'Geo', 'Environment', 'JobName', 'JobStarttime', 'JobEndtime',
    'JobProcessingTime', 'JobTaskname', 'TaskStarttime', 'TaskEndtime', 
    'TaskProcessingTime', 'TotalActiveInventory', 'NewInventoryAdded',
    'TotalActiveSKUs', 'TotalActiveStores', 'TotalCalculatedAllocations',
    'TotalActiveAllocations'  

UNION ALL        

SELECT 
    CAST([JobTaskID] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 
    CAST([Geo] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 
    CAST([Environment] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 
    CAST([JobName] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 
    CAST([JobStarttime] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 
    CAST([JobEndtime] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 
    CAST([JobProcessingTime] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 
    CAST([JobTaskname] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 
    CAST([TaskStarttime] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 
    CAST([TaskEndtime] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST([TaskProcessingTime] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 
    CAST([TotalActiveInventory] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 
    CAST([NewInventoryAdded] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 
    CAST([TotalActiveSKUs] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 
    CAST([TotalActiveStores] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),   
    CAST([TotalCalculatedAllocations] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),  
    CAST([TotalActiveAllocations] AS NVARCHAR(MAX))       
FROM 
    ctbl_jobReport 
ORDER BY 
    JobTaskID
```

The table `ctbl_jobreport` does contain the `JobTaskID` column:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ctbl_jobReport]
(
    [JobTaskID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    [Geo] [nvarchar] (128) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [Environment] [nvarchar] (128) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [JobName] [nvarchar] (128) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [JobStarttime] [datetime] NULL,
    [JobEndtime] [datetime] NULL,
    [JobProcessingTime] [nvarchar] (128) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [JobTaskname] [nvarchar] (128) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [TaskStarttime] [datetime] NULL,
    [TaskEndtime] [datetime] NULL,
    [TaskProcessingTime] [nvarchar] (128) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [TotalActiveInventory] [int] NULL,
    [NewInventoryAdded] [int] NULL,
    [TotalActiveSKUs] [int] NULL,
    [TotalActiveStores] [int] NULL,
    [TotalCalculatedAllocations] [int] NULL,
    [TotalActiveAllocations] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

When I run the two select statements individually, I do not see that error

Comment: Neither of your queries give names to the columns. You have `SELECT 'JobTaskID'` but you should have `SELECT 'JobTaskID' as JobTaskId`

Comment: `CAST`ing all your columns to an `nvarchar(MAX)` makes no sense as well. It's impossible, for example, for a `int` to be over 4,000 characters. What are you really trying to achieve here?

Comment: The error message is very precise, you are using a *union* operator and you have not aliased the `JobTaskID` you are ordering by (or any column) in the select list - you need to obey SQL Server's instructions here!

Comment: This looks like a classic example of an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: This looks like you're trying to add in column names to the result set, perhaps for exporting to a csv or excel? note that this would only work if you also include an additional column to indicate the headings row as the first row and then order by it, otherwise there is nothing that guarantees the unioned row is always the first row.

Comment: well ,he could do: order by case when JobTaskID = 'JobTaskID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, JobTaskID

Comment: What is the point of this anyway, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Putting aside *why* you would want to do something like this (which is almost certainly trying to solve a different problem with the wrong kind of solution), you can achieve it by correctly aliasing the fields (as you're using a `UNION`) so they can be sorted on, and then adding an additional static field to force the "column headers" to be returned first, before the actual data:

```
CREATE TABLE #ctbl_jobReport
(
    [JobTaskID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    [Geo] [nvarchar] (128) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [Environment] [nvarchar] (128) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [JobName] [nvarchar] (128) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [JobStarttime] [datetime] NULL,
    [JobEndtime] [datetime] NULL,
    [JobProcessingTime] [nvarchar] (128) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [JobTaskname] [nvarchar] (128) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [TaskStarttime] [datetime] NULL,
    [TaskEndtime] [datetime] NULL,
    [TaskProcessingTime] [nvarchar] (128) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [TotalActiveInventory] [int] NULL,
    [NewInventoryAdded] [int] NULL,
    [TotalActiveSKUs] [int] NULL,
    [TotalActiveStores] [int] NULL,
    [TotalCalculatedAllocations] [int] NULL,
    [TotalActiveAllocations] [int] NULL
)

insert into #ctbl_jobReport values
('GeoValue','EnvValue','JobNameValue','2023-01-01','2023-06-01','JobProcTimeValue','JobTasknameValue','2023-01-02','2023-05-31','TaskProcTimeValue',1,2,3,4,5,6),
('GeoValue2','EnvValue2','JobNameValue2','2023-01-01','2023-06-01','JobProcTimeValue2','JobTasknameValue2','2023-01-02','2023-05-31','TaskProcTimeValue2',1,2,3,4,5,6),
('GeoValue3','EnvValue3','JobNameValue3','2023-01-01','2023-06-01','JobProcTimeValue3','JobTasknameValue3','2023-01-02','2023-05-31','TaskProcTimeValue3',1,2,3,4,5,6),
('GeoValue4','EnvValue4','JobNameValue4','2023-01-01','2023-06-01','JobProcTimeValue4','JobTasknameValue4','2023-01-02','2023-05-31','TaskProcTimeValue4',1,2,3,4,5,6)

SELECT 
    1 as orderRef,
    'JobTaskID' as JobTaskID,
    'Geo' as Geo, 
    'Environment' as Environment, 
    'JobName' as JobName, 
    'JobStarttime' as JobStarttime, 
    'JobEndtime' as JobEndtime,
    'JobProcessingTime' as JobProcessingTime, 
    'JobTaskname' as JobTaskname, 
    'TaskStarttime' as TaskStarttime, 
    'TaskEndtime' as TaskEndtime, 
    'TaskProcessingTime' as TaskProcessingTime, 
    'TotalActiveInventory' as TotalActiveInventory, 
    'NewInventoryAdded' as NewInventoryAdded,
    'TotalActiveSKUs' as TotalActiveSKUs, 
    'TotalActiveStores' as TotalActiveStores, 
    'TotalCalculatedAllocations' as TotalCalculatedAllocations,
    'TotalActiveAllocations' as TotalActiveAllocations  

UNION ALL        

SELECT 
    2,
    CAST([JobTaskID] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 
    CAST([Geo] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 
    CAST([Environment] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 
    CAST([JobName] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 
    CAST([JobStarttime] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 
    CAST([JobEndtime] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 
    CAST([JobProcessingTime] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 
    CAST([JobTaskname] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 
    CAST([TaskStarttime] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 
    CAST([TaskEndtime] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST([TaskProcessingTime] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 
    CAST([TotalActiveInventory] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 
    CAST([NewInventoryAdded] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 
    CAST([TotalActiveSKUs] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 
    CAST([TotalActiveStores] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),   
    CAST([TotalCalculatedAllocations] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),  
    CAST([TotalActiveAllocations] AS NVARCHAR(MAX))       
FROM 
    #ctbl_jobReport 
ORDER BY 
    orderRef,
    JobTaskID

drop table #ctbl_jobReport
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a db.view
then apply the separate query
Select * from db.view order by JobTaskID